# In mongodb is it possible to query by sub-object?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an doc in mongo:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("54eb5189ad9685bbb622ca52"),
  "header" : {
    "title" : "Project Name 1",
    "header_img" : "project_name_1.png",
    "project_stats" : {
        "sqFt" : 20000,
        "tons" : 300,
        "duration" : "6 months",
        "type" : "education facility",
        "summary" : "Give quick summary of problem solved."
    }
},
"row_project_detail" : {
    "project_logo" : "project_name_1_logo.png",
    "header" : "Project Name 1 was a project where...",
    "paragraph" : "blah blah blah blah"
},
"row_1" : {
    "img" : "project_name_2.png"
},
"row_2" : {
    "img_1" : "project_name_3.png",
    "img_2" : "project_name_4.png"
},
"row_3" : {
    "img" : "project_name_5.png"
},
"row_4" : {
    "img" : "project_name_6.png"
}
}
```

I have tried to query by `db.projects.find({ header: { title: "Project Name 1"} });` but it does not produce results. How can I query by the `title` key in the `header` object? Is this possible or do I simply need to duplicate the `title` key from the `header` sub-object and put that at the root of the doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dot notation:

```
db.projects.find({ "header.title": "Project Name 1"});
```